# Divs are not spacing corectly between design view and live view

Tags: css, html, browser, margin

Im trying to give a div some small amount of margin-top. it works fine and does what I want in the design view but in live view or in a browser it shows nothing as if like that line of code does not exist. 
Im new to stackflow so ill try and post the code im using.

```
<div class="overallWrap">
<div class="backgroundWrap">
    <div class="topWrap">
        <div class="dvd"></div>
    </div>      
    <div class="titleWrap">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="socialWrap">
                <div class="facebook"></div>
                <div class="twitter"></div>
                <div class="link"></div>         
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="midWrap">
        <div class="tools"></div>
        <div class="menuWrap">
            <div class="ps"></div>
            <div class="fl"></div>
            <div class="dw"></div>
            <div class="blender"></div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="bottomWrap">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="quote"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css is:

```
* {
color:black;
}
body {
    background-color:#000;
.overallWrap {
    background-color:white;
    width:920px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:1100px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-left:215px;
    margin-top:40px;
    }
.backgroundWrap {
    width:900px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:1060px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    background-image:url(dgltest.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
.dvd {
    width:300px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:60px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    float:right;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.topWrap {
    width:900px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:65px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
}
.titleWrap {
    width:900px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:265px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
}
.title {
    width:780px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:265px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    float:left;
}
.socialWrap {
    width:115px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:150px;
}
.leftWrap {
    width:75px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:100px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
}
.facebook {
    width:30px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:30px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
}
.twitter {
    width:30px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:30px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    float:right;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.link {
    width:30px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:30px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.midWrap {
    width:900px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:410px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
}
.tools {
    width:30px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:410px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    float:left;
    margin-left:37px;
}
.menuWrap {
    width:270px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:410px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    float:right;
}
.ps {
    width:270px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:80px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-top:10px;
}
.fl {
    width:270px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:80px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-top:30px;
}
.dw {
    width:270px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:80px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-top:30px;
}
.blender {
    width:270px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:80px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-top:20px;
}
.bottomWrap {
    width:900px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:320px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
}
.logo {
    width:200px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:240px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    margin-top:80px;
    float:left;
}
.quote {
    width:650px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    height:280px;/*DO NOT CHANGE*/
    float:right;
}
```

The overallWrap is a div that is the total srceen size i want to display. The inside will be whit and the outside black so it will look like a big white rectangle in the middle of a black screen. Then ive made a smaller backgroundWrap div to fit inside the overallWrap with margin borders on the top of 12px and the left 10px. My problem is when I look at it in the browser or live view the code in the backgroundWrap for margin top does nothing so i cant see a 12px white strip if that makes sense. aarrgh its driving me made. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What framework is design view and live view?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the box model in your design view is not collapsing margins. The proper behavior in margins is for them to collapse. Try using padding instead.

```
.backgroundWrap { padding-top: 12px; }
```

In short, when you set a `margin-top: 40px` around the wrapper and `margin-top: 12px` in the inner div the inner margins will collapse with the wrapper so you won't see a separation in between.